# How to include computed fields in Pydantic custom model serialization?

Tags: python, pydantic

I am trying to create a custom model serializer that converts model fields to CamelCase, however `computed_field`s aren't being included in the `model_dump()` output.

I suspect it has to do with how I'm iterating over `self` in `ser_model()`, but I'm having trouble figuring it out.

```py
import pydantic


class SuperSickClass(pydantic.BaseModel):
    bing_bong: int

    @pydantic.computed_field
    @property
    def bippity_boink(self) -> int:
        return self.bing_bong + 1

    @pydantic.model_serializer
    def ser_model(self):
        out = dict()
        for field_name, field_value in self:
            camel_case_key = ''.join(word.capitalize() for word in field_name.split('_'))
            out[camel_case_key] = field_value
        return out

if __name__ == '__main__':
    super_sick_instance = SuperSickClass(bing_bong=1)
    print(super_sick_instance.model_dump())
    # actual output: {'BingBong': 1}
    # desired output: {'BingBong': 1, 'BippityBoink': 2}
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

A Pydantic dev helped me out with a solution [here](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/7364)

This problem can be solved using the `populate_by_alias` parameter in the `ConfigDict`, combined with the `by_alias` parameter in `model_dump()` being set to `True`.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict, computed_field

def to_camel(string: str) -> str:
    return ''.join(word.capitalize() for word in string.split('_'))

class SuperSickClass(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(alias_generator=to_camel, populate_by_name=True)

    bing_bong: int

    @computed_field
    @property
    def bippity_boink(self) -> int:
        return self.bing_bong + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    super_sick_instance = SuperSickClass(bing_bong=1)
    print(super_sick_instance.model_dump(by_alias=True))
    # resulting output: {'BingBong': 1, 'BippityBoink': 2}
```